# updating table only where there is a key match

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

at first I wanted to update a table (product prices) by importing a csv file but I don't think that is possible.

So I created a temporary table and imported 2 columns: products_id, products_price

I think tried running this sql:

```
UPDATE products p SET p.products_price=(
    SELECT t.products_price
    FROM temp_table t
    WHERE t.products_id=p.products_id
)
```

This updated all the prices where there was a products_id match but also set all the other products to 0.00

What can I do to only update when there is a match and ignore other product_ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a update join query like

```
UPDATE products p 
JOIN temp_table t ON t.products_id=p.products_id
SET p.products_price = t.products_price;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use inner join

```
update table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
set column_name = t2.column_name
where t1.id =t2.id
```